# Changing Scala lazy val behaviour

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

Suppose I have a String type lazy val :

```
    Class LazyVals { 

     lazy val message = "I am lazy on + " + System.currentTimeMillis().toString    

     def changeLazy = { message + " Not!!" }
    }
```

Will changeLazy change the "evaluate once only" nature of message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code to calculate `message` will be evaluated once only. You can't change this behavior.

`currentTimeMillis` will be called only once. Concatenation `message + " Not!!"` will be performed on each `changeLazy` call with the same result, but can be optimized by `jvm`.